# Given n rectangles coordinates, find area of region where k rectangles intersect?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computational-geometry

Given a list rectangles [R1, R2, R3] defined by their lower left and upper right `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]` coordinates, and a value k.

Is there an optimal way to find area where k rectangles overlap?

For example:

```
R1: [(1, 1), (5, 5)]
R2: [(4, 4), (7, 6)]
R3: [(3, 3), (8, 7)]

rectangles = [R1, R2, R3]
k = 2
```

The area which is overlapped by two rectangles is 8.

[image: Grid Image]

Brute force way to solve this is calculate the min and max of x-axis and y-axis coordinates and then used that create a grid and increment one for each cell within rectangle. At the end iterate over the grid to compute number of cells which have a value as k to find the solution.

The approach has a complexity of `O(n^3)`, assuming each each rectangle is of size `n x n` and there are n rectangles.

Is there a run time optimal way to approach this problem?

Comment: Your complexity statement is a bit misleading. Actually, it is `O(AT + AU)`, where `AT` is the sum of all rectangle areas and `AU` is the area of the union (or the bounding box, depending on how you do the final iteration over all grid cells). While theoretically still having the same complexity, you might get faster in practice with an auto-partitioning kd-tree. I.e., you would not record overlaps per grid cell but per tree cell, of which there might be much fewer depending on the size distribution of rectangles.

Comment: I'm going to  go with "Quadtree".

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to analyze collections of rectangles is with a sweep line algorithm. Imagine a vertical line that starts at the left of the collection and scans to the right.  Store a set of the rectangles that currently intersect the line, initially empty.  This set needs to be updated when the line passes a vertical side of any rectangle: adding or removing a rectangle in each case. To make scanning efficient, use a sorted list of the x coordinates of the verticals.

In this case, you'll also need a way to efficiently determine the intervals of the scan line that are covered by k or more rectangles.  That can be done efficiently by maintaining an interval tree.

Depending on details, efficiency ought to be roughly O(n log n) for n rectangles with maybe an additional term for the maximum overlap depth.  I'll let you work out the details.

Comment: Can you expand on the **interval tree** part ? What will this be and how would you go about building it ?